# Appending php array for desired row outputs

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am building a friends list of logged in user verified by session id. I have code that query's, results, and loops perfectly. BUT, it is posting an integer (maybe the id#?), (as this is my unique identifying condition of the select query) AND what I want is to output the (users) table rows of "firstname" and "lastname" instead of the user-id!

Sounds simple enough, yet, I lack the knowledge to make it work! So, here I am inquiry from the world of coders for help! Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
// Get Friend Array 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users
        INNER JOIN friends
        ON users.id = friends.id 
        WHERE (friends.user1='$u' OR friends.user2='$u' AND friends.accepted='1')"; 
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
        array_push($my_friends, $row["user2"]); 
        array_push($my_friends, $row["user1"]);
        }

        //remove your id from array 
        $my_friends = array_diff($my_friends, array($u)); 
        //reset the key values 
        $my_friends = array_values($my_friends); 
        mysqli_free_result($query);
        // Loop through $my_friends array and build results
        foreach($my_friends as $friends => $v2);
        $friends .= '<a href="user.php?u='.$v2.'"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; ';
}
```

Here is my html code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true">
        <?php
            echo "<li>$friends</li>"; 
        ?> 
        </ul>
```

It is the last line of code 
`$friends .= '<a href="user.php?u='.$v2.'"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp; ';`that I'm trying to workout. How the syntax of that line should be to add ($row["users.firstname"] and $row["users.lastname"]) and somehow not list the user "$id #" that is joining the two tables of (users) and (friends) in the select query!

It may be that I need a different array altogether for what I want, and If you know of the right way to do this, please inform me of how to do it...Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

What I understood that you are missing User's `id` in `row`. This issue is because php array can not have two `keys` with same name.
Change you query little bit like below

```
$sql = "SELECT *, friends.id as friendsID FROM users
        INNER JOIN friends
        ON users.id = friends.id 
        WHERE (friends.user1='$u' OR friends.user2='$u' AND friends.accepted='1')";
```

Now you will have `id' as User Id and`friendsID` as Friend's ID

Comment: well, my `id` in the code is working good. It `InnerJoins' both tables. But, the reason I need to join them in the first place, is because I want to pull rows `firstname and lastname` from the Users table and add them to my variable `$friends` so that my echo in the html  listview will display their names. Right now, the array pulls the right users and links to their profile, but the listview is only showing the integer 0?